# found and error on HackerRank, or maybe it is not properly explain

Tags: java

This is about counter-game/problem
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counter-game/problem

Louise and Richard have developed a numbers game. They pick a number and check to see if it is a power of 2. If it is, they divide it by 2. If not, they reduce it by the next lower number which is a power of 2. Whoever reduces the number to  wins the game. Louise always starts.

so for 5.
*is not a power of 2, we reduce it by restarting the next closest number of power of two.  5-4 = 1
Louise wins the game
but hacker rank throws me an errors and tells me it should be Richard.

note:Louise if n = 1 Richards wins, Louise starts the game

Am I missing something here?

**for input n = 5 the expected Result according to Hackerrank is 'Richard', yet if I read this correctly the expected result should be 'Louise'**

this is the code

```
static boolean winnerIsLouise = true;

public static String counterGame(long n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        switchWinner()
        return getWinner();
    }

    while (n > 1) {
        System.out.println("winner luise : "+winnerIsLouise);
        if (isPowerOfTwo(n)){
            n=n/2;
        }else{
            n = n - previusPowerOfTwo(n);
        }
        if (n==1)
            return getWinner();
        switchWinner();
    }

    return null;
}

private static String getWinner() {
    return winnerIsLouise ? "Louise" : "Richard";
}

private static void switchWinner() {
    winnerIsLouise = !winnerIsLouise;
}


public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(long x) {

    return x != 0 && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}

public static long previusPowerOfTwo(long n) {

    char[] chars = Long.toBinaryString(n).toCharArray();
    double length = chars.length - 1;
    double base = 2;
    Double res = Math.pow(base, length);
    return res.longValue();
}
```

Comment: I think I found the description. initial condition correct? shouldn't Louise loose if she starts with `n = 1` - "If they initially set counter to 1, Richard wins. Louise cannot make a move so she loses."

Comment: Louise starts
winnerIsLouise = true;
There is another rule:  Update If they initially set counter to 1, Richard wins.

Comment: exactly, but your code says Louise wins when starting with `n = 1` (not Richard as you just confirmed)

Comment: Yes.. thats a mistake from my side.  but the issue itself is for number 5

Comment: hard to believe they did it wrong for such an obvious case, are you sure that you are interpreting the error message correctly? Anyway, that should be discussed there then. By the description you gave, `n = 5` should really result in "Louise" (confirmed by some solutions from "hackerrank.com")

Comment: Thats my point exactly..  thats why i pasted all the problem there

Comment: maybe you should include the result in the question - I mean the error message. And I just noted the println at the start of the loop - isn't  that being misinterpreted by the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspect, you (probably) are misinterpreting the *results*, or better, the input data of the site - it would have been so much easier if you had posted the *results* as I've asked in my last comment.

Output from site:

[image]

or, as text, since that will better show the mistake:

> ```
> Input (stdin)        Expected Output
>
>   5                    Richard
>   1560834...           Richard
>   1768820...           Louise
>   1533726...           Richard
>   1620434...           Louise
>   1463674...
> ```

as you can see, there is *missing* one output: `5` is not one of the values for `n`, it is the **count of numbers** to be tested! The first output, `Richard`, is for `1560834...`

Here the corresponding part of the description:

> The first line contains an integer , the number of testcases

Answer (score 1):

Should your while loop be n>=0 instead of n>1?

This would allow 2^0 which equals 1, which would take Richards score down to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: `n` is being checked against 1 and method returns if it is equal

Comment: I meant for n to be allowed as 0

Comment: zero should not be possible if starting with `n > 0`

Comment: input is n>0, this is a restriction, so if n=1 richards win, if its 2 then is power of two, so it divides, we get a 1 and Louise wins.  and as @Carlos Heuberger wrote, zero is not possible

Comment: but still a good point, for *security*  it would have been better to consider the possibility of an erroneous entry. Maybe have some check if `n > 0` or return if `n <= 1`; and have the loop as `while (true)`...